# get Symbol description in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to get a Symbol description in TypeScript just like it's done with JavaScript?

Example,

```
const x = Symbol('x');
console.log(x.description) // returns 'x' in Javascript but error in TypeScript.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ES2019 feature, so you need to add `"lib": ["es2019"]` to `compilerOptions` section of your tsconfig.json.